# ArcMap export map function not working properly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.5

I've got 3 different data frame's in my file'; all with a standard arcgis background. Whenever I try to export my layout view; the pdf/emp/png etc only loads one out of three background maps. What can be done about this?

Comment: You can see the three data frames in the layout view in ArcMap but if you export it just one of them is visible?

Comment: Within a layout you can see as many dataframes as you like but when you export your layout make sure all the dataframes you need to print are within the layout page.

Comment: It's possible your MXD got corrupted.  What happens if you try to export with multiple data frames from a different MXD?